# Why doesn't building my UWP Unit Test project produce a test dll

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to run unit tests from the command line.
For this, I need the test dlls, as per this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182490.aspx

In the Prerequisites section on that page, it says I need to "Run a Unit Test and Fix Your Code"

**Question 1:** Do I need to *run* tests from VS to be able to run them from command line? Surely not?

Now to the more important bit. When I build my solution, regardless of whether it's via VS or command line using MSBuild, I do not get any dlls generated for my tests.

I know this is for C++ but thought might still be relevant https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a89c2173-90e6-47b2-af8e-48865969cbca/msbuild15-does-not-create-a-dll-file-after-building-the-c-native-unit-test-project?forum=msbuild. (not that it helped of course).

**Question 2:** Why don't my unit test dlls get generated when building?

Comment: I thought I'd be used to this by now but it still continues to amaze me how .Net development is more of a constant battle of getting SDKs, packages, compilers, IDE, frameworks, dlls, and a plethora of other things working well together than it is about simply coding. If it wasn't for this beautiful language called C# (and it really is the only little thread Microsoft are hanging by imo), I'd probably would've ended up being a dentist (much easier problems to drill into).

Comment: I understand, but still much better than the JavaScript's new-framework-a-day world :-D .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UWP is a bit different from other projects when it comes to Unit Testing. Universal Windows Apps run in a sandbox to make sure they don't do things they don't have permissions for. For this reason, the unit test project is not a simple DLL only, but in fact a full-fledged UWP app (and the generated executable has `appx` extension), that is launched and performs the tests.

That said, you can still launch the unit test project from the console using a special command as you can see in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33771590/running-universal-windows-unit-tests-from-the-command-line).

```
vstest.console.exe /Platform:x64 AppPackages\UnitTestProject1_1.0.0.0_x64_Debug_Test\UnitTestProject1_1.0.0.0_x64_Debug.appx
```

Comment: I see. Well the good thing is I do get a .appx generated upon build, so will try to run this from command line using vstest.console.exe (once I fix cert issues) and get back to you.

Comment: Not a requirement for this question but still a bit relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49442040/can-vstest-console-exe-run-an-appx-without-a-security-certificate