# Can vstest.console.exe run an appx without a security certificate

Tags: c#, uwp, msbuild, vstest.console.exe

I'm trying to set up automated builds on my build agent using MSBuild on the command line. The two projects I'm focussed on at the moment are a UWP and it's associated unit test project.

To build, I have to use this:

```
/p:AppxPackageSigningEnabled=false
```

Else, I get this error:

```
error APPX0101: A signing key is required in order to package this project. Please specify a PackageCertificateKeyFile or PackageCertificateThumbprint value in the project file.
```

However, this does not generate a .cer security certificate. So when I run vstest.console.exe, I get this error:

```
error 0x800B0100: The app package must be digitally signed for signature validation..
```

**Question:** Can vstest.console.exe be made to run without a .cer, and if not, how can I get everything building and my tests running as well? I don't want devs to use temporary .pfx files.

Comment: use the same commant while running: /p:AppxPackageSigningEnabled=false as a parameter It is an MSBuild parameter it will create a unsigned package.

Comment: @shrot Sorry I don't quite follow. Do you mean I should pass that same parameter `/p:AppxPackageSigningEnabled=false` to vstest.console.exe?

Comment: yes pass the same parameter to vsts.console.exe along with the dlls of the build.

Comment: @shrot It complains with an error saying unrecognised parameter. Also, there are no dlls. It’s UWP so just an appx.

Comment: Seriously? Downvoting? Step forward and maybe explain yourself whoever you are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A UWP package must be signed, so it should not be able to made to run without a .cer. Please see the [Best Practices for Signing Certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/auto-build-package-uwp-apps#best-practices-for-signing-certificates) and [Create a certificate for package signing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/create-certificate-package-signing) topics to create a signing certificate firstly.

Comment: Thanks. I’ve already seen those pages (which really need updating). And I’ve successfully created a certificate and singed the app via command line. I really just needed to know if all that’s necessary. Where is it documented that UWP apps need to be signed in order to run them, in precisely those words or equivalent? And if that really is the case, what’s the point of `/p:AppxPackageSigningEnabled=false`?

Comment: @Ash Error will occur when you deploy a Windows Store app packages if the package is unsigned, see the **0x800B0100** error code and the corresponding **Suggestions** part *Only signed Windows Store app packages can be deployed* in this document https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj835836(v=vs.85).aspx. On other hand, the `/p:AppxPackageSigningEnabled=false` is used when sometime you will require Appxpackage not to be signed, rather to be signed by some one else.

Comment: Thanks Breeze. Really think this should be mentioned in big bold letters on one of the getting started pages of UWP, not within some troubleshooting page under some error description. Anyway, this answers my question, so accepting.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a way to run a UWP unit test using `vstest.console.exe` without having to install any certificate:
Pass to `vstest.console.exe` the `.appxrecipe` file instead of the `.appx` file.

It will deploy the UWP unit test app from its current build location and be able to start the tests.